# Can I set the intent/context for the next DialogFlow interaction (for push notifications)?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to be able to send "push" notifications to Twilio integrated users, which I can do out-of-band to get the message (by using the Twilio API). But I'd like to "notify" Dialogflow so if the user responds to the message, it will already be at the correct follow-up intent.

Is there some way set DialogFlow to "expect" a reply after a user completes an action else.

USE CASE:
Platform sends as SMS with, "Did your pizza arrive?"

If the user replies: Yes, or No, there needs an input context pre-set or the system won't know what question is being answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another intent with some input context that you set through the api when you ask "Did your pizza arrive?"

Create a yesno entity to match yes/no in the user response. Create an intent as shown in the picture. Only set the `pizza-confirm` context when you ask 'Did your pizza arrive' so as you won't enter the intent accidentally from somewhere else and remove other similar contexts that might trigger other follow-up intents with a yes/no answer (if you have any). You would have to resolve the @yesno value in a fulfillment and respond differently depending on the value.

Or, you can create two follow-up intents, one matching `yes` and the other `no`.

Also, you need to know which session to update so you don't update someone elses dialog session.

See the API-reference: (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.contexts/create)

[image: dialogflow example]